# Is the ID attribute within a Yii model protected from editing?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, model

I created a simple Yii Model using giix, which inherits from ActiveRecord. Using the rules function I defined that a certain Value is unsafe, so it cannot be changed because it indicates which user it belongs to. When you submit the form it sends the id of the data via the form to apply the change to the right data set. What happens if you change this id? If it is the only way for Yii to find the data, you could change random stuff? Or does Yii check for that automaticly using a built in function?

Btw. You get only the results that belong to a specific user because I used defaultScope, however defaultScope applies only to SELECT queries, not to INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE.

EDIT:

I changed the ID that is submit in the URL. Now it points to a different record. This record wont have that specific user value assigned to it. However, Yii doesnt check against that I guess, so am I still able to edit that record, just by changing the ID given in the URL?

Thanks for any suggestions and answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but I think you might not be clear as to how the unsafe validator works in Yii.

Check out the [reference page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/) for validation.

Basically, when you get a record from the database into an ActiveRecord model, all of the model's attributes will be populated from the database values. However, if there is no input on the form in which the record's ID is specified (as there well shouldn't be, since it is typically the primary key for that database table), then it will not be updated in your model or in the database upon form submission.

In other words, let's say that I have a table with the following characteristics:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`username` varchar(39) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`password` varchar(39) NOT NULL,
```

And then I create a model of that table, it'll be populated with all three columns for any record it pulls. However, if I were to create an "update your password," form, I should never add an ID line. So, when I pull a record and hold it in the model, and then update the value for password in savings that model, the ID attribute should never be exposed to the end user.

Now, when I go to save the record after the form is submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['MyForm'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['MyForm'];
    $model->save();
}
```

The model is first going to be run through any validation rules before saving, that is correct. But the only items for which I should set validation rules are those which may have incorrect or incomplete input from users. So, it might make sense to do something like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('username', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,100}$/i', 'message' => 'Come on now, make a name that makes sense!'),
            array('password', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[\w\d]{6,18}$/', 'message' => 'Don\'t use special characters in your password!'),
    }
```

Both of those will check, using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) (and please forgive any regex typos, but it looks right at first glance), whether the username and password fit the pattern.

But what would happen if I were to declare an attribute as [unsafe](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh22)? All that is doing is preventing me from setting the value posted in the form to the model using massive assignment.

So, if I were to update my rules() with:

```
    public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                array('username', 'unsafe'),
                array('password', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[\w\d]{6,18}$/', 'message' => 'Don\'t use special characters in your password!'),
        }
```

Then when a form is submitted, the call to set all of the attributes in the model equal to the form values:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['MyForm'];
```

The unsafe attribute (in this case, username) will simply not be set.

But it won't matter for ID, since it shouldn't be in the form, anyway. Either it will have already been pulled from the database when a query is performed, or else it will (with proper schema definition) be automatically created upon insertion of a new record into the database.

Comment: Ive added some extra explanation, maybe it is clearer now. It was a bit confused I have to admit :P

Comment: No, Yii won't be able to determine whether the URL has been changed manually unless you code in something to check this. You can use Yii's [accessRules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth), which you can place in the model and set to perform a check to see if a user is permitted to access certain pages. Also, the best thanks is an upvote or accepting the answer. =)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed to know :D Answer is marked accepted, need some more reputation to upvote it :P will be done as soon as possible ;) so thank you very much!

Comment: "But it won't matter for ID, since it shouldn't be in the form, anyway." - This line is very wrong when it comes to POST data injected by hackers - It will matter BIG TIME then just saying ;)